# Express Js - Using handlebars partial views

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am learning express and trying to use partial views with it.

**App.js**

```
var app = express();

var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars').create({defaultLayout: 'main'});

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

handlebars.loadPartials(function(err, partials){
    console.log(partials);
});

app.set('port', process.env.port || 4000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home');
});

function getWeatherData(){
    console.log('Building Weather Data');
    return {
        locations: [
            {
                name: 'Portland',
                forecastUrl: 'http://www.wunderground.com/US/OR/portland.html',
                iconUrl: 'http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/couldy.gif',
                weather: 'Overcast',
                temp: '54.1 F (12.3 C)'
            },
            {
                name: 'Bend',
                forecastUrl: 'http://www.wundergroud.com/US/OR/Bend.html',
                iconUrl: 'http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif',
                weather: 'Partly Cloudy',
                temp: '55.0 F (12.8 C)'
            },
            {
                name: 'Manzanita',
                forecastUrl: 'http://wunderground.com/US/OR/Manzanita.html',
                iconUrl: 'http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/rain.gif',
                weather: 'Light Rain',
                temp: '55.0 F (12.8 C)'
            }

        ]
    };
};

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(!res.locals.partials)
        res.locals.partials = {};

    res.locals.partials.weather = getWeatherData();
    next();
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Application started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '; press ctrl+ C to end.');
});
```

**home.handlebars**

```
<h1> This is Partials home</h1>
{{>weather}}
```

**main.handlebars (default layout)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Partials Example
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{{body}}}
    </body>
</html>
```

**weather.handlebars (partial view)**

```
<div class="weatherWidget">
    <label>Data received for: {{partials.weather.locations.length}} cities</label>
    {{#each partials.weather.locations}}
        <div class="location">
            <h3>{{name}}</h3>
            <a href="{{forecastUrl}}">
                <img src="{{iconUrl}}" alt="{{weather}}">
                    {{weather}}, {{temp}}
            </a>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
    <small>Source: <a href="http://wunderground.com">Weather Underground</a></small>    
</div>
```

Now when i run the application I cannot see the data populated on the page. This example I am following is from book called Web development with Node and Express.

Node version I am using is v0.10.36 and for handlebars I am using express3-handlebars plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to prepopulate the data. i.e., run

```
...
getWeatherData()
app.use(function(req, res, next){...
```

after the function to populate the values. I think the book does this (I've used it before)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the name of "*res.locals.partials.weather*" to "**res.locals.partials.weatherData**" [[issue link]](https://github.com/EthanRBrown/web-development-with-node-and-express/issues/28)
2. You should populate the **res.locals.partials.weatherData** before you render the home page, move the code:

   ```
   app.use(function(req, res, next){
       if(!res.locals.partials)
           res.locals.partials = {};
       res.locals.partials.weather = getWeatherData();
       next();
   })
   ```

   before the following:

   ```
   app.get('/', function(req, res){
       res.render('home');
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`app.use(function(req, res, next){..})` before `app.get('/')`

Comment: Could you elaborate your question a bit more?